# Using EXPORTHOW to make declarator that acts like "sub"

Tags: object, metaprogramming, raku, rakudo, meta-object-protocol

The excellent 2011 Advent of Raku post [Meta-programming: what, why and how](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/meta-programming-what-why-and-how/) provides a few clear examples of using `EXPORTHOW` to create a declarator that acts like `class`.  Here's the first:

```raku
my class SingleInheritanceClassHOW
    is Metamodel::ClassHOW
{
    method add_parent(Mu $obj, Mu $parent) {
        if +self.parents($obj, :local) > 0 {
            die "Multiple inheritance is forbidden!";
        }
        callsame;
    }
}
my module EXPORTHOW { }
EXPORTHOW.WHO.<class> = SingleInheritanceClassHOW;
```

Is there a way to do something similar for a declarator that acts like `sub` (that is, that allows the use to supply a signature and block, rather than allowing the user to supply attributes and methods)?  The metaclass of a `Sub` is `ClassHOW`, so it *seems* that something similar should be possible, but I'm not seeing a way to do so.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The `EXPORTHOW` mechanism is only for overriding the metaclass that will be used for package declarators, with the slight extension that `EXPORTHOW::DECLARE` also performs a grammar tweak that introduces a new package declarator.

While one can call `.HOW` on a `Sub`, the result does not relate to the subroutine itself, but rather the metaclass of the `Sub` type, of which a subroutine is an instance.

Really, `EXPORTHOW` is an "easy things easy" mechanism (to the degree it's fair to call anything relating to meta-programming easy!) It was also a straightforward thing to provide: the parsing of package declarations was already extremely regular, and the compiler already maintained a mapping table from package keyword to metaclass, so providing a way for a module to replace entries in that table (or add new ones for `DECLARE`) was barely a few hours of compiler hackery.

Routines are vastly less regular, even if that's only somewhat apparent syntactically. While packages pretty much parse the keyword (`class`, `role`, `grammar`, etc.) and what follows is the very same syntax and semantics for all of them (modulo roles permitting a signature), there are separate parse rules and semantics behind each of `sub`, `method`, `macro`, and `rule`. Their interaction with the overall compilation process is also rather more involved. The ongoing RakuAST effort is bringing a bit more order to that chaos, and ultimately - when coupled with slangs - will offer a way to introduce new `sub`-like constructs, as well as to give them semantics.