# EXPORTHOW and DECLARE - what are they?

Tags: raku, rakudo

I have read an [article](https://perl6advent.wordpress.com/2011/12/14/meta-programming-what-why-and-how/) by Jonathan Worthington about meta programming.
There he writes:

> Do do this, we stick it in the EXPORTHOW module, under the name
> “class”. The importer pays special attention to this module, if it
> exists.

At he same time [here](https://github.com/jnthn/oo-monitors/blob/master/lib/OO/Monitors.pm6#L111) Jonathan uses `DECLARE`.
Is there any documentation about that and other similar things? What and when should one use? What are other special things importer looks for?

I tried to search the official docs but failed to find anything there.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: I'm afraid not. All the metamodel is underdocumented. In this case, `DECLARE` is used to kinda create new syntax when exporting, instead of just exporting the name of the class.

Comment: where can we at least look at all possible things like that?

Comment: See also [jnthn's answer to SO Q **Using `EXPORTHOW` to make declarator that acts like "sub"**](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70342023/1077672).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> where can we at least look at all possible things like that?

Aiui the source code of the [Rakudo compiler](https://rakudo.org/) is as good as you're gonna get.

It looks to me like `EXPORTHOW` is [processed here](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/World.nqp#L976-L1030), with `DECLARE` in particular [here](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/blob/master/src/Perl6/World.nqp#L998-L1011), as part of `World.nqp`.

Afaik the `World` class is:

- An internal implementation specific detail of Rakudo. It is not part of the Raku language. It is not something you can rely on. It is not officially supported.
- Written in nqp. nqp is not Raku. It's essentially a small subset of Raku focused on being a good programming language for writing compilers.

Comment: thank you for that! as far as I can see EXPORTHOW might also have SUPERSEDE and COMPOSE keys. Do You happen to know what they do as well?

Comment: No. First, please know that what I did for my answer was to fire off [a search within the compiler source code for `EXPORTHOW`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?p=3&q=exporthow), skim the list of matches, click on likely prospects, search for `DECLARE` in each, and settle on providing the two `World` links. For `COMPOSE` I see `NYI('EXPORTHOW::COMPOSE')` and know `NYI` will mean "Not Yet Implemented". [A search for `SUPERSEDE`](https://github.com/rakudo/rakudo/search?q=supersede) shows an `.NYI` for that too, and the `Exception` match suggests it's for overriding an existing declarator.

Comment: Please note that `World.nqp` does not exist in the RakuAST branch, which will become the main branch of Rakudo this year.  All of its logic will be incorporated into RakuAST classes.  So learn from the concepts in `World.nqp`, not from the code!  :-)